# Where can I find the issue tracker for the smart mining?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, smart-mining

I'm trying out the smart mining. Seems a bit wonky. Just wondering where I can follow its issues. Github?

Comment: Thanks for trying it out! If you file an issue, remember to include your OS, etc.

Comment: @revler1082, I'm not familiar with a pull request or tag to attach to the GitHub issue. Can I reference your name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues. It looks like I must have a lot more filler for the post to be accepted.